# How to build a sidecar container for passing files from a machine outside of the Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: php, docker, backend, kubernetes, coreos

I have a noob question. If I'm using a docker image that uses a folder located in the host to do something, Where should be located the folder in the kubernetes cluster? I'm ok doing this with docker since I know where is my host filesystem but I get lost when I'm on a kubernetes cluster.

Actually, I don't know if this is the best approach. But what I'm trying to do is build a development environment for a **php backbend**. Since what I want is that every person can run a container environment **with their own files** (which are on their computers), I'm trying to build a sidecar container so when launching the container I can pass the files to the php container.

The problem is that I'm running kubernetes to build development environment for my company using a vagrant (coreos + kubernetes) solution since we don't have a cloud service right now so I can't use a persiten disk. I try NFS but it seems be too much for what I want (just pass some information to the pod regardless of the PC where I am). Also I try to use hostPAth in Kubernetes but the problem is that the machines where I want connect to the containers are located outside of the kubernetes cluster (Vagrant + CoreOS + Kubernetes so I-m trying to expose some container to public IPs but I can not figure out how to past the files (located in the machines outside of the cluster) to the containers.

Thanks for your help, I appreciate your comments.

Comment: Do the files need to mirror what is on the developer system (e.g. live update) or can you bundle them up at deploy time (using a custom wrapper script around kubectl)?

Comment: I would prefer to mirror what is on the developers computers since the idea is that they work in the code (modified the files) and automatically the backend containers update the output (web page). If I can do it with a wrapper at deploy time and then update the code in the containers (update the files) it will work too.

Answer (score 2):

Not so hard, actually. Check my gists may give you some tips:

https://gist.github.com/resouer/378bcdaef1d9601ed6aa

See, do not try to consume files from outside, just package them in a docker image, and consume them by sidecar mode.

Comment: What is sidecar mode?

Comment: sidecar mode is: some containers in Pod will be used by other containers

Comment: Is this a special setting in Kubernetes or a design pattern?

Comment: just a container design pattern, no setting required